# Does stripping whitespace from between tags affect screen readers reading of a page?

Tags: accessibility, whitespace, screen-readers

In order to replicate a design it has been necessary to split the individual words in a block of text and wrap them in  tags. An external backend development team is asking that all whitespace be removed from between spans - not in itself an issue but we are wondering whether it will have an impact on how screen readers will dictate the text to a user. Will it call it out as a single mega-word?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you have a text format like this?

`This is<span>some</span>text.`

How it will be pronounced by a screen reader depends on the type of navigation being used. There are some modes that will stop at each element, pronouncing it as:

`This is` (next) `some` (next) `text.`

Whereas (next) would be the user input to continue to the next (text) node.

However, this will not always be the case. A visual impaired person will most likely use the mode to continue reading, which will strip the tags and concatenate the text like: `This issometext.`

So if possible, you should add a space before and after your text, like this:

`This is <span>some</span> text.`or: `This is<span> some </span>text.`

If this is not possible, you could use a CSS-sollution, like:

```
span:after {
    content: "\00a0";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zomry - it is more that the test has to be rendered:


`<span>Some</span><span>more</span><span>text</span><span>in</span><span>here</span>`


The integration team are using a minification algorithm that removes inter-span whitespace - fine for css as I can build in margins to separate words, but I am not sure how a screen reader will interpret this. 


Thank you for that though, that is interesting insight into how the screen reader would function.

Comment: Take a look at my CSS solution in my original post.
I was able to do some more testing, so I had to update my solution a bit. It didn't seem to work with a regular space, but it works if you use a non-breakable space. It’s bit of a hack, but it seems to do the trick.
If your whole text is in span-elements, you only need :after. If it depends, you should use :before and :after. Do not use margin or padding as an alternative for space. It will look okay for normal users, but it will not change how a screen reader will read it.